# Green color or color green?

Tags: differences, word-order, colors, adjective-position

Can I replace all of the bold text with *color green*? I don't know when should I use *green color* and when *color green*.

> I have my wall painted in **green color** and it is generally believed that green is an eye friendly color unlike red. The mild **green color** is a popular color which does not look too violent or too dull. I liked this color even in my childhood and that I can be sure from the dominant green usages in my childhood paints. My teachers sometimes laughed at my weakness on **green color** when I painted a green sun and green moon. I am not quite sure how my fascination started growing on **green color**.

Comment: Dupe of this [question on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/39737/10446).

Comment: @DanBron The answers on that post are not satisfactory, certainly not for this question, which is different.

Comment: Since colors are kind of an artsy-fartsy thing, so are terms used to refer to them -- you can use several different schemes, depending on the "mood" you wish to convey.  "I have my wall painted in green color" is not right, though (but don't ask me to quote the rule).  "I have my wall painted **a** green color" is better, or simply "... painted green" or "... painted the color green."  And you can of course rearrange to say "My walls are painted green/a green color/the color green," or something of that nature.

Answer (score 2):

Most simply, people would say "I painted my wall green. Use of "in" is unnecessary, and "color" is redundant and wordy.  (What else could green be--green taste, green sound?)

Also, your teacher laughed at your weakness for green, not on green. Again, no "color."  (You may say, though, "the color green" here.)

If you're a native speaker of other languages, Spanish for one, the use of the word "color" in this context is much more frequent, and transferral of this usage into English is tempting, but it's better to let the color name stand on its own.

Comment: +1 You should highlight "for" and "on" to make your answer clearer. For example: "at you weakness **for** green, NOT **on** green." But I agree "green color" is a bit wordy and it is often (not always!) redundant.

Comment: lovely green color is correct or lovely color green?!

Comment: A lovely green color is better, but you could just as easily say a lovely green.  Also, a lovely shade of green

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence I would use the indefinite article.

> I have my wall painted in **a** *green color*

Here the noun *color* is singular, and the adjective *green* is placed in front, which is often the case in English. But that doesn't mean you cannot also say

> I have my wall(s) painted **in** green
>   I have painted my wall(s) green
>   I have painted my wall the **color of** green

But instead of the expression the *colour of green*, which is perfectly fine I would suggest using the expression *shade of green* because it sounds more natural to me.

The American English corpus in [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=color%20green%2Ccolor%20of%20green%2Cgreen%20color%2C%20shade%20of%20green&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolor%20green%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolor%20of%20green%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgreen%20color%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshade%20of%20green%3B%2Cc0) seems to agree. *Shade of green* (yellow line) is used more often than *colour of green* (red line), but unsurprisingly *green color* is by far and away the most common expression.

[image]

> The wall is [painted in] a cool **shade of** green

For variety you could experiment with the following adjectives: *cool*, *minty*, *light*, *moldy*, *dark* etc.

---

EDIT
@Steve Littman's answer reminded me that we can say: *I love the color green*

Consequently, I would slightly rephrase the last sentence in your text to

> I'm not quite sure how my fascination started growing for **the color green**

Comment: Patient but pointed answer that many users (like myself) would not have put themselves out to answer. Well done!

Comment: @MickeyMouse "It's **a** lovely green" OR "It's **a** lovely green color" Nouns usually come AFTER adjectives E.g., *a lovely green house/wall/color* etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your first sentence you can use "green in color" or "the color green" instead of "green color". To a native or experience English speaker "green color" sounds ambiguous and grammatically incorrect.

Example:I have my wall painted "green in color"... 
        or
       :I have my wall painted "the color green"...

In the second sentence you can use "color green".

Example: The mild "color green"...

Comment: You meant if I in every situation use the 'color green' or "green in color" that would be correct?!and make sense?!

Comment: Are you sure that we can use 'mild color green'. I think it is like dark/light green color  not dark/light color green.reddish-brown/yellowy-green/deep blue etc colour